# How to implement Multiple Choice in node.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I would like to make multiple choice in my code.
Let me explain:

With cheerio, I can find the text of a class of HTML Web code

```
Let elo = $('.statPlayer).text().trim(); 

//Here elo = "Iron I" Or "Iron II" or "Iron III" or "Iron IV" or "Bronze I" Until "Bronze IV" etc... Until Challenger
```

And now I would like: When elo start with `Ir` for Iron  or `Br` for Bronse or `Si` for Silver... until `Ch` to Challenger, `LOGO` becomes one of the corresponding values ​​below

```
    const iron = ('<:Iron:702831042112782437>') // it's value of log
    const bronze = ('<:Bronze:702831061012578384>');
    const silver = ('<:Silver:702831073771388928>');
    const gold = ('<:Gold:702831081778577459>');
    const plat = ('<:Platine:702831091823673414>');
    const diams = ('<:Diamant:702831105752956969>');
    const Master = ('<:Master:702831167384191007>');
    const GMaster = ('<:GrandMaster:702831178855743618>');
    const Chall = ('<:Chall:702831190268313670>');
```

And so we would get:

```
If `ELO` = Gold II or Gold IV => `LOGO` = `gold`
```

I don't know if it's understandable but I tried to do my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```js
let logo;
switch (elo.slice(0, 2)) {
  case 'Ir':
    logo = iron;
    break;
  case 'Br':
    logo = bronze;
    break;
  case 'Si': 
    log = silver;
    break;
  // etc...
  case 'Ch':
    logo = Chall;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it's that ! I'll try this one. Thank's you.